# cannot modify a column on DBaaS ORA-01779

Tags: sql, oracle

I am struggling with Oracle DBaaS issue, I have another version of schema and its working fine on local docker Oracle image (account with same priviliges etc), but its invalid on real DBaaS:

from the beginning:

working:

```sql
alter table SCHEMA_NAME.table_1 add column_A char(1 byte) default 0 not null;
```

working:

```sql
create table SCHEMA_NAME.temp_table as
select SCHEMA_NAME.table_1.table_2_id as tem,
       SCHEMA_NAME.table_2.id as dis,
       SCHEMA_NAME.table_3.id as pap, SCHEMA_NAME.table_3.column_A
from   SCHEMA_NAME.table_1
       join SCHEMA_NAME.table_2
       on SCHEMA_NAME.table_1.table_2_id=SCHEMA_NAME.table_2.id
       join SCHEMA_NAME.table_3
       on SCHEMA_NAME.table_2.table_3_id=SCHEMA_NAME.table_3.id
order by SCHEMA_NAME.table_1.table_2_id asc;
```

failed:

```
ORA-01779 cannot modify a column which maps to a non key-preserved table
```

```sql
update (select SCHEMA_NAME.table_1.id,
               SCHEMA_NAME.table_1.column_A oldsdi,
               SCHEMA_NAME.temp_table.tem,
               SCHEMA_NAME.temp_table.column_A newsdi
        from   SCHEMA_NAME.table_1,
               SCHEMA_NAME.temp_table
        where SCHEMA_NAME.table_1.id=SCHEMA_NAME.temp_table.tem)
set oldsdi=newsdi;

alter table SCHEMA_NAME.table_3 drop column column_A;
drop table SCHEMA_NAME.temp_table;
```

How to fix it and why its working on local docker Oracle image and not on real DBaaS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simplify the query by using a `MERGE` statement:

```sql
MERGE INTO SCHEMA_NAME.table_1 dst
USING SCHEMA_NAME.temp_table src
ON (src.tem = dst.id)
WHEN MATCHED THEN
  UPDATE SET dst.column_A = src.column_A;
```

If it does not work then you probably have multiple rows in `SCHEMA_NAME.temp_table` with the same `tem` value so it is impossible for the database to work out which value it should update the destination table with. In that case you need to fix the data.

> why its working on local docker Oracle image and not on real DBaaS?

Probably because the local Docker image only has unique `tem` values in the table and the DBaaS table has non-unique `tem` values in the table. What you need to do in that case is to fix the data.

Comment: Thank You, its working fine, tested on few DBaaS :)